# Add filter to wp_dropdown_pages() or wp_dropdown_categories() - no select container?

Tags: filters, wp-list-pages, dropdown, categories

I'm working with `wp_dropdown_pages()` and `wp_dropdown_categories()` and both are always outputting a `<select>`-box with its `<option>`s as items.

Is it possible to add a filter/hook to this funtions so I get just the `<option>`s without being wrapped inside of a `<select>`

The reason I'm asking is that I want to combine pages and categories into one dropdown.

I couldn't find a param to set this!

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A filter called `wp_dropdown_pages` exists in the [`wp_dropdown_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages) function. That filter allows you to modify the output of the function. However, for the thing you want to do I would not recommend using this filter since this will apply to all code that calls `wp_dropdown_pages()`, including plugins.

So, one way to approach your situation may be to simply strip off the `<select>` markup. You could use regular expressions like this:

```
$ddp = wp_dropdown_pages(array(
    'echo' => FALSE, // return the HTML instead of outputting it
));
$ddp = preg_replace('~^<select[^>]*+>\s*~', '', trim($ddp)); // opening select tag
$ddp = preg_replace('~\s*</select>$~', '', $ddp); // closing select tag
```

That way you are left with just the `<option>`s. Do the same for the category dropdown, concatenate the strings and wrap it with your own `<select>`.

Note: I am well aware that [using regex to parse HTML is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/130169). It’s dirty, yet, it does the job.

A cleaner way to build the select list you want is to avoid the built-in dropdown functions altogether and instead use the functions [`get_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) and [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories). Those return an array, which you can loop over to build your own markup. A basic example follows.

```
$pages = get_pages();
$categories = get_categories();

$html = '<select>';
foreach ($pages as $page)
{
    $html .= '<option value="page-'.$page->ID.'">'.esc_html($page->post_title).'</option>';
}
foreach ($categories as $category)
{
    $html .= '<option value="category-'.$category->term_id.'">'.esc_html($category->name).'</option>';
}
$html .= '</select>';
```

Comment: Good answer.  I was halfway finished with my answer but yours was much more thorough.