# Search box with field hidden till drop down selection is made

Tags: custom-taxonomy, jquery, dropdown

I have a search widget with a drop down populated with my custom taxonomies. I need one of the other input fields to only show when a certain taxonomy or its children are selected.

Before you say this is only a jquary question, please bare with me. I think I need to edit wp_dropdown_categories() with Walker_CategoryDropdown to add data-select="select1" in the  tag.

I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/QMYpM/) code that does what I want I just dont know how to implement it.

The HTML (Updated to reflect my code):

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="equipfilter" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">
    <fieldset>
        <?php
            $dropdown_args = array(
                'taxonomy'          => 'exc_equipment_cat',
                'name'              => 'exc_equipment_cat',
                'show_count'        => 1,
                'orderby'           => 'name',
                'hierarchical'      => true,
                'echo'              => 0,
                'walker'            => new Walker_SlugValueCategoryDropdown
                );
            /*
            wp_dropdown_categories( $dropdown_args );
            */?>
            <?php
            $select = wp_dropdown_categories($dropdown_args);
            $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 data-select='select1'>", $select);
            echo $select;
            ?>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="hidden" data-select="NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE">
        <legend>Kw Range:</legend>
        <input type="text" name="kw_min" placeholder="min" value><br />
        <input type="text" name="kw_max" placeholder="max" value>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Price Range:</legend>
        <input type="text" name="pr_min" placeholder="from" value><br />
        <input type="text" name="pr_max" placeholder="to" value>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" id="filtersubmit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

The css:

```
.hidden {
 display:none;   
}
```

The jquery (Updated to where its working now when tested with my test category):

```
jQuery(function ($){
    $(function(){
        $('.postform').change(function() {
            var selectData = $(this).attr("data-select");
            var selectValue = $(this).val();
                    $('.hidden').hide();
             if($("fieldset[data-select='" + selectData + selectValue +"']").css("display") == "none"){
                 $("fieldset[data-select^='" + selectData + "']").hide();
                 $("fieldset[data-select='" + selectData + selectValue +"']").show();
             }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I could strip the select tags and then just add my own. The code given by Geert [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50981/add-filter-to-wp-dropdown-pages-or-wp-dropdown-categories-no-select-contai) but even he says its dirty :-) `$ddp = wp_dropdown_pages(array(
    'echo' => FALSE, // return the HTML instead of outputting it
));
$ddp = preg_replace('~^<select[^>]*+>\s*~', '', trim($ddp)); // opening select tag
$ddp = preg_replace('~\s*</select>$~', '', $ddp); // closing select tag`

Comment: Got the data-select added by using `<?php $select = wp_dropdown_categories($dropdown_args); $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 data-select='select1'>", $select); echo $select; ?>` and changing the echo in my $dropdown_args to 0

Comment: Added `$('.hidden').hide();` to hide fieldset if required category was deselcted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My full working code for those interested

```
    <?php 
    // Equipment Category Dropdown, thanks https://gist.github.com/2902509
    class Walker_SlugValueCategoryDropdown extends Walker_CategoryDropdown {

            function start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args) {
            $pad = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $depth * 3);
            $cat_name = apply_filters('list_cats', $category->name, $category);
            //$output .= "<select name='exc_equipment_cat' id='exc_equipment_cat' class='postform' data-select='select1'>";
            $output .= "\t<option class=\"level-$depth\" value=\"".$category->slug."\"";
            if ( $category->term_id == $args['selected'] )
                $output .= ' selected="selected"';
            $output .= '>';
            $output .= $pad.$cat_name;
            if ( $args['show_count'] )
                $output .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;('. $category->count .')';
            $output .= "</option>\n";
            //$output .= "</select>";
        }
    }

    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_equipment_search' );

    function register_equipment_search() {
        register_widget( 'Equipment_Search' );
    }
    //add_action("widgets_init", array('Equipment_Search', 'register'));
    class Equipment_Search extends WP_Widget {

        function Equipment_Search() {
            $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'agriquip', 'description' => __('Displays the Equipment Search Form', 'agriquip') );
            $control_ops = array( 'width' => 200, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'agriquip-widget' );
            $this->WP_Widget( 'agriquip-widget', __('Equipment Search', 'agriquip'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
        }

        function widget( $args, $instance ) {
            extract( $args );

            $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );
            $tract_id = isset( $instance['kwtax'] ) ? $instance['kwtax'] : false;   
            $tract = wp_list_pluck(get_terms('exc_equipment_cat', array('parent' => $tract_id)), 'slug');
            $tractparent = get_term_by('id', $tract_id , 'exc_equipment_cat');
            $tractparent = $tractparent->slug; 


            echo $before_widget;

            // Display the widget title
            if ( $title )
                echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

            ?>
            <div>
            <script type="text/Javascript">
            jQuery(function ($){
                $(document).ready(function () {
                        $(".kw").hide();
                    });

                $(function(){
                    $('.postform').change(function() {
                        var selectData = $(this).attr("data-select");
                        var selectValue = $(this).val();
                        $('.kw').hide();
                         if($("fieldset[data-select='" + selectData + selectValue +"']").css("display") == "none"){
                             $("fieldset[data-select^='" + selectData + "']").hide();
                             $("fieldset[data-select='" + selectData + selectValue +"']").show();
                         }
                    });
                });
                var values = <?php echo json_encode($tract); ?>;
                values.push ("<?php echo $tractparent; ?>");
                jQuery('.postform').change(function(){
                    var j = jQuery(this);
                    if(values.indexOf(j.val()) >= 0) {
                        jQuery('.kw').attr('data-select', 'select1' + j.val());
                    }
                });
            });
            </script>
            <form role="search" method="get" id="equipfilter" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">
                <fieldset>
                    <?php
                    echo 'KW Category Id' .$tract_id;
                        $dropdown_args = array(
                            'taxonomy'          => 'exc_equipment_cat',
                            'name'              => 'exc_equipment_cat',
                            'show_count'        => 1,
                            'orderby'           => 'name',
                            'hierarchical'      => true,
                            'echo'              => 0,
                            'walker'            => new Walker_SlugValueCategoryDropdown
                            );

                        wp_dropdown_categories( $dropdown_args );

                        $select = wp_dropdown_categories($dropdown_args);
                        $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 data-select='select1'>", $select);
                        echo $select;
                        ?>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="kw" data-select="select1">
                    <legend>Kw Range:</legend>
                    <input type="text" name="kw_min" placeholder="min" value><br />
                    <input type="text" name="kw_max" placeholder="max" value>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Price Range:</legend>
                    <input type="text" name="pr_min" placeholder="from" value><br />
                    <input type="text" name="pr_max" placeholder="to" value>
                </fieldset>
                <input type="submit" id="filtersubmit" value="Search" />
            </form></div>

            <?php

            echo $after_widget;
        }

        function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
            $instance = $old_instance;

            //Strip tags from title and name to remove HTML 
            $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
            $instance['kwtax'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['kwtax'] );

            return $instance;
        }

        function form( $instance ) {

            //Set up some default widget settings.
            $defaults = array( 'title' => __('Equipment Search', 'agriquip'), 'kwtax' => '');
            $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults );
            ?>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'agriquip'); ?></label>
                <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" class="widefat" />
            </p>

              <p>
                <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('kwtax'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('kwtax'); ?>" class="widefat" style="width:100%;">
                    <?php foreach(get_terms('exc_equipment_cat','parent=0&hide_empty=0') as $term) { ?>
                    <option <?php selected( $instance['kwtax'], $term->term_id ); ?> value="<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>      
                </select>
            </p>

    <?php
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To add the data-select to the select tag use

```
 <?php 
   $select = wp_dropdown_categories($dropdown_args); 
   $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 data-select='select1'>", $select); 
   echo $select; 
 ?>
```

then change the echo in $dropdown_args to 0.

I will take the jquery part of the question to the right platform

Answer (score 0):

To hide the kw field I used just jQuery because if Javascript is disable then the field will still show but if I hide it with css then it will stay hidden. Here is my code to hide the field:

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
        jQuery(function ($){
            $(document).ready(function () {
                    $(".kw").hide();
                });

            $(function(){
                $('.postform').change(function() {
                    var selectData = $(this).attr("data-select");
                    var selectValue = $(this).val();
                    $('.kw').hide();
                     if($("fieldset[data-select='" + selectData + selectValue +"']").css("display") == "none"){
                         $("fieldset[data-select^='" + selectData + "']").hide();
                         $("fieldset[data-select='" + selectData + selectValue +"']").show();
                     }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
```